# Running UI Automator Viewer from android-sdk on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, android, user-interface, ubuntu-18.04, android-studio

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I need to automate some android app with Appium. I need to use UI Automator Viewer from android-sdk. I run it like this

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/
$ export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/
```

and after

```
$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
$ ./uiautomatorviewer
```

But then I get the error:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/home/tosik/Android/Sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the java-8-jdk. It fixed the problem for me.